# Spark SQL error : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: extraneous input '$' expecting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am forming a query in a String Builder like below :

**println(dataQuery)**

```
Execution started at 2019-10-31 02:58:24.006019 PST
res245: String =
" SELECT transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, cast($counter as Int) AS arrival_days, cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String) as Arrival_date,trim(cast(getDayOfWeek(cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String)) as String)) as weekday,cast(ceil($counter/7)as Int) as week_no, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,gross,0)) as GROSS, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbc,0)) as NBC, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbr,0)) as NBR, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,dp,0)) as DP, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,gross,0)) as DAYGROSS, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbc,0)) as DAYNBC, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbr,0)) as DAYNBR, , sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,dp,0)) as DAYDP,
FROM BASE_DLV
GROUP BY transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, arrival_days, arrival_date, weekday, week_no
```

when executing it as sql **val data3 = spark.sql(dataQuery)**

getting below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '$' expecting {'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', 'DIV', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 74)

== SQL ==
 SELECT transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, cast($counter as Int) AS arrival_days, cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String) as Arrival_date,trim(cast(getDayOfWeek(cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String)) as String)) as weekday,cast(ceil($counter/7)as Int) as week_no, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,gross,0)) as GROSS, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbc,0)) as NBC, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbr,0)) as NBR, sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,dp,0)) as DP, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,gross,0)) as DAYGROSS, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbc,0)) as DAYNBC, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbr,0)) as DAYNBR, sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,dp,0)) as DAYDP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
FROM BASE_DLV
GROUP BY transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, arrival_days, arrival_date, weekday, week_no

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:641)
  ... 71 elided
```

also tried to run the same query directly

```
val data2 =spark.sql(s"""SELECT transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, 
cast($counter as Int) AS arrival_days, 
cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String) as Arrival_date,
trim(cast(getDayOfWeek(cast(date_sub(date_add(transaction_created_date,$counter),day(transaction_created_date)) as String)) as String)) as weekday,
cast(ceil($counter/7)as Int) as week_no,
sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,gross,0)) as GROSS, 
sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbc,0)) as NBC, 
sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,nbr,0)) as NBR,
 sum(if(arrival_day_base<=$counter,dp,0)) as DP, 
 sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,gross,0)) as DAYGROSS, 
 sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbc,0)) as DAYNBC,
  sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,nbr,0)) as DAYNBR, 
  sum(if(arrival_day_base==$counter,dp,0)) as DAYDP
FROM BASE_DLV
GROUP BY transaction_created_date, txn_mth, txn_mth_id, breakout_y_n, arrival_days, arrival_date, weekday, week_no""")
```

and it is executing successfully

```
Execution started at 2019-10-31 02:51:32.451289 PST
data2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [transaction_created_date: string, txn_mth: string ... 14 more fields]
Execution completed at 2019-10-31 02:51:34.532190 PST in 2.08 s
```

but getting same parse error on trying

```
val data3 = spark.sql(s"""$dataQuery""")
```

can anyone please help with the using the stringBuilder in **spark.sql()** without the issue

Answer (score 0):

`dataQuery` should have counter defined and evaluated

```
val counter = 10
val dataQuery = s"select $counter as cnt" //gives select 10 as cnt

spark.sql(s"$dataQuery").show()
```

shows

```
+---+
|cnt|
+---+
| 10|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are noticing is in scala multi line queries need """ triple quotes around multi line SQL statements.